# How to turn 4.1M 1.22B 3K to numbers in power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

my data number came in text form, for example: 4.1M 1.22B 3K
Is there a way to turn them back into numbers like 4100000 for 4.1M

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've tried to supply you with an answer. However, you do not make clear if your data is in text to begin with of that Power BI automatically changes it into a short version. It is better to make this clear to people reading, since we do not know your problem and now we will just have to assume.

Comment: Yeah, can you explain your issue with more description.

Comment: thanks for all the replies, it is actually the data I receive is in the short form. When I import the data into powerbi, I am unable to treat it as a number.

Comment: You could make a new column in the query editor where you make an if/else statement for all cases. I'm not sure what all the syntax it but I can imagine it being something like 'if [column] contains "M" THEN LEFT([column],2) * 1000000 else if' etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using card visualization you have feature to change count for thousands, millions etc. It depend on visualization.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to explain what that feature is, where to find it. This is vague and will help OP only partially. Also, you forget that future readers might need the answer and it would be better to have it written out as much as possible (Without adding fluff). 

That being said, I also still have trouble formulating the right answers and the only way to learn is to try, so thanks for answering anyways!

Comment: Sure, my bad. sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the following steps:

1. Select the visual where you want to change this notation
2. Click on the paint roller in the Visualisations pane
3. You have already activated labels, expand this part
4. Here you can choose how to show values, select whatever you want

Keep in mind however that big numbers are hard to read and easy to read wrong. It is worth considering to keep them as 4.1M and 1.22B since it keeps them nice and compact. This is especially the case if you use visualisations that grow over time, where overlap might occur easily if you have written-out numbers.

Also, refer to the following documentation for explanation on the Microsoft website:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-customize-title-background-and-legend

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to clean data in Power Query. It is a bit cumbersome, and personally I would contact whoever is responsible for my data source and ask if I could get data in a better format.

The idea is to first figure out what type of multiplier you want to apply to each row, then clean out the "foreign" symbols in the `Sample Value` column - this is generated using a nifty trick with `Character.FromNumber`, see link: https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2015/11/19/keep-only-numbers-in-power-query/ )after that it is simply to convert the original column to a number (might have to remove `#"Replaced Value"` step depending on your locale) and create a final column that multiplies the number with the multiplier.

You can paste the below into a blank query to see for yourself:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMtEz9FWK1YlWMtQzMnICs4y9IQLGSrGxAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Sample Values" = _t]),
    #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each if Text.Contains([Sample Values], "B") then Number.Power(10,9) else if Text.Contains([Sample Values], "M") then Number.Power(10,6) else if Text.Contains([Sample Values], "K") then Number.Power(10,3) else 1),
    CharsToRemove = List.Transform({33..45,47,58..126}, each Character.FromNumber(_)),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Conditional Column", "Result", each Text.Remove([Sample Values],CharsToRemove)),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Added Custom",".",",",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Result"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Replaced Value",{{"Result", type number}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Result Value", each [Result]*[Custom], type number),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Result Value"})
in
    #"Removed Other Columns"
```